# Comma usage in "One of the..., is ..."

Tags: grammaticality, commas

Given a sentence such as,

> One of the reasons for certain large beetles developing teleportation technology, is to ensure annual pilgrimages to their home planet are well-attended and enjoyable for all.

Why is there a comma?  Is this correct usage, and does it have a name?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The comma should not be there. It is called "a mistake."

The subject is "*One of the reasons for certain large beetles developing teleportation technology*" and the verb is "*is*".

Subject and verb should not be separated by a comma.

Comment: Unless you're Captain Kirk. ;)

Comment: That's reassuring.  I've seen this a few times, and was unsure if it existed in the grey area of grammar where rules are more contextual--in this case, my only guess was that a lengthy subject (like this) merited a comma as a sort of delimiter.

Comment: @TTT - Many people feel that they must insert a comma in a long sentence like that, even though it's not merited on the basis of grammar, or because  there would typically be a pause there in speech.

Comment: it's only a mistake if the author knows better.  Otherwise it's known as "an error".

Comment: You may sometimes see such commas in pre-written speeches or scripts as a breathing aid to the person reading this out loud. But it does not fit standard prescriptive rules of grammar.

Comment: @Jason Unless you, are Captain Kirk ;)

Comment: The subject is simply "one".  Prepositional phrases can be set off by commas (for instance: "Your stories, at their best, are still terrible."), but in @TTT's sample, the comma seems to be an attempt by the writer to insert an arbitrary pause.  Grammatically, it's wrong and shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 5):

Although not grammatically correct, the comma serves to avoid incorrect parsing of part of the sentence as "... teleportation technology is to ensure ...". That would result in incorrectly parsing the object of "developing" as though it were the subject of "is", which would be a fundamentally incorrect understanding of part this relatively complex sentence.

It forces the reader to see "for certain large beetles developing teleportation technology" as more tightly bound to "reasons" than to "is".

It could be made clearer by rephrasing as two separate sentences so that "reasons is" occurs in the second sentence. For example:

*There are reasons for certain large beetles developing teleportation technology. One of the reasons is to ensure annual pilgrimages to their home planet are well-attended and enjoyable for all.*

or

*Certain large beetles are developing teleportation technology. One of the reasons for this is to ensure annual pilgrimages to their home planet are well-attended and enjoyable for all.*

The author may have been using this grammatical anomaly ("mistake") to try to achieve a similar cognitive separation between "technology" and "is" without rephrasing into multiple sentences.

Comment: I think it's likely that the author did that unknowingly -- the same need to disambiguate exists when speaking, so we tend to pause there, and many writers will insert a comma wherever they would take a breath.